# Interval of convergence for a series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I am currently trying to determine the interval of convergence, but I keep getting 0 for all my questions. I have attached one of the questions that I am unable to solve completely and I would really love it if someone can point me in the right direction and explain to me how to correctly solve this question. [image]

I'm not sure how to continue further and I feel that I did it wrong too since if I try to continue , I get a very ugly result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{(\frac{k+1}{k})^k(k+1)}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{k})^k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0$

Comment: How did you go from first step to second step?

Comment: By dividing numerator and denominator by $k^k$